# How to downsample within recursive feature elimination using caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, feature-selection, rfe

Consider the data frame `data` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
num = sample(5:20, replace = T, 20)
id = letters[1:20]
loc <- rep(id, num)
data <- data.frame(Location = loc)
data[paste0('var', seq_along(1:10))] <- rnorm(length(id) * sum(num))
```

Assuming `data` is my training data; Each row represents measurements that were taken on a randomly sampled individuals from populations identified by the grouping variable `Location`. I want to use recursive feature elimination to identify the best subset of predictors for predicting `Location`. Analogously, I want to understand how much variation each of the predictors explain in `Location` (i.e., which ones are most important, and how much more important are they). I have read how this can be done using the caret package using something like this:

```r
library(caret)
subsets <- 1:9
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs, method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 10, verbose = F)
lmProfile <- rfe(data[,2:10], data[,1], sizes = subsets, rfeControl = ctrl)
```

In my `data` example, considering the unbalanced number of samples in each `Location`, I want to use down sampling to ensure that the same number of samples is being considered across the levels of `Location` upon each iteration. Could someone demonstrate how I might do this?